# relative path with respect to given path

Tags: php, function, path

let I have two path

```
$abs_path = "/opt/lampp/htdocs/projectname/data/archive/201408/thumbnails/";
$php_path = "/opt/lampp/htdocs/projectname";
```

Is there any **function  in PHP** which can take base of arbitrary path and return path based of given path with respect to arbitrary path

```
relative_path($abs_path,$php_path);
```

returns `/data/archive/201408/thumbnails/`

we can do with `**preg_replace`**

or with  **`str_replace`** : `str_replace($php_path, '', $abs_path);`
but that is not sufficient

but I am looking for some string function or any function which works with path ,  similar to  [`base_convert`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.base-convert.php) which works with numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Even tried to use [str_replace()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)?